# Keyboard animation in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, viewcontroller

In my Login view controller i use UITextFieldDelegate and animation to up view when keyboard is open.
Code:

in viewWillAppear()

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

in ViewController

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;    
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height - 30
            imageLogo.alpha = 0.0
            self.animateTextField(true)
        }
    }
}
func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
    var movement = (up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    })
}
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    imageLogo.alpha = 1.0
    self.animateTextField(false)
}
func DismissKeyboard(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

When i change language in keyboard animation runs again
How can i fixed it ???

Thanks...

Comment: replace the relative `CGRectOffset(...)` method with some absolute calculation, that might help on you – however I'm not sure why it is a problem for you if the animation runs again... you could elaborate that particular part, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two or more UITextFields in on View Controller
For each UITextField i add myTextField.delegate = self

In this situation if you use animation for hide/show keyboard it is not work good

Solutions:
Put .delegate = self only for first text field
and it is work good